# formatting number input fields with jquery.number

Tags: jquery

i want to format an input field with european number style, 2.000,56 EUR instead of 2,000.56 $. iam using jquery.number.js, the input into the fields works, but getting back the value failds.

2.000,56 -> 200.056,00

input field ok
database value ok
input field afer reload wrong

iam using this code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.number.js"></script>
$('#kaltmiete').number( true, 2, ',', '.' );

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6">
   <div class="formBlock">
   <label for="kaltmiete">Kaltmiete</label><br/>
   <div class="input-group input-group-md">
   <input type="text" name="kaltmiete" id="kaltmiete" value="<?php echo $row["kaltmiete"]; ?>" class="form-control" />
   <div class="input-group-addon">EUR</div>
   </div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you Looking for this..

http://numeraljs.com/

Just look and follow thee instructions and examples.

Good luck... ['}